# Javascript: How to catch an empty Facebook Graph json object? --> { "data" : [ ] }

Tags: javascript, json, facebook-graph-api

I am working with Facebook Graph Api. I am getting new pages of data under the json format and when there is no more data I run into the following:

json object:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

How can I catch this empty json in javascript? I have tried each of the following individually with no success:

```
if(json.data[0].length == 0){
    alert('empty');
}

if(json.data[0] == ''){
    alert('empty');
}

if (json.data.length == 0) {
    alert('empty');
}

if (json["data"].length == 0) {
    alert('empty');
}
```

Additional details:

This is the code where I want to check the empty data array. Everything else works fine when I receive non-empty json from Facebook.

```
$.get(url, function(json){
    pages[pagenumber+1]=json.paging.next;

    //Where I want to check for empty json

    $.each(json.data,function(i, data){
        $("#thumbnail"+i).attr("src", data.picture);
});
},'jsonp');
```

Updated....!The solution for me was to use:

if (json.data[0])

Comment: Do you have a link to a live example of the code?

Comment: That is very strange, maybe you should do a test where you alert(json.data) and alert(json.data.length) and see what it thinks is there. Might be the length comes out as 1 or some low number.

Comment: I just tried, when there is data I get [object Object] and lenght 1. When there its empty I do not get the alert message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the following:

```
if (json.data[0]) {
alert('empty');
}
```

Its the only way I got it to work and actually catch the empty data structure.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(json.data.length == 0){
    alert('empty');
}
```

Comment: Is json a parsed object (as in a JSON object), or is it still in a String literal state? If the later, then it would fail.

Comment: They are parsed json objects I can access them using the . operator when they have date in them.

Comment: Is this processed synchronously or asynchronously? I.e. was the call completed and returned from facebook before the check was performed?

Comment: Are you certain that {
  "data": [
  ]
} is returned? Can you double confirm this using http watch?

Comment: Ok I monitored the traffic and here is what is sent back from FB:                       /**/ jQuery164008223470184020698_1316082751508({
   "data": [
      
   ]
});To me this is my jQuery callback and the content which is as expected the empty data array. Any ideas on why I cant catch this>

Answer (score 2):

Like that:

```
var json = { "data": [] }

if (json.data.length == 0) {
    alert('empty');
}
```

or that:

```
var json = { "data": [] }

if (json["data"].length == 0) {
    alert('empty');
}
```

Comment: These code snippets do work alone. They do not work when I receive the empty json from Facebook. Something else must be happening.

Comment: It should not make any difference whatsoever, especially if you are certain that the JSON object is a de-serialized object and not a string.

Additionally, the last code snippet should have taken care of the empty `data` property on `json`. Why would you need to test for it anyway?

Comment: I am going through pages of json data and I reach the end of the collection so I want to do something else...

Answer (score 0):

In your example here, you need to re-order the statements. Not sure if you are running them in this order but you need to do

```
if(json.data.length == 0){
    alert('empty');
}
```

**before** you do

```
if(json.data[0].length == 0){
    alert('empty');
}
```

This might be why it isn't working for you

Comment: I have tried each example individually I've added more details in my description. I've tried each variation at //Where I want to check for empty json

Comment: try:
`$.get(url, function(json){
    pages[pagenumber+1]=json.paging.next;

    //Where I want to check for empty json
 if(json.data){
  $.each(json.data,function(i, data){
   $("#thumbnail"+i).attr("src", data.picture);
 }
});
},'jsonp');`

Comment: I don't think he put all of the `if` statements altogether. I hope not.

Comment: Abby: I tried the following:                                                               $.get(url, function(json){
   if(json.data){
   pages[pagenumber+1]=json.paging.next;   
   $.each(json.data,function(i, data){
    $("#thumbnail"+i).attr("src", data.picture);
   });
   alert('data');
   }
   else{
    alert('no more data!');
   }
  },'jsonp');                                                                                 Caught all the cases when there was data but it did not catch the else, so something does not compute when the empty array comes through.

Comment: if(json.data && json.data.length>0) ?